# How do I pass a new line character to Twilio's python library for SMS via a variable

Tags: python, twilio, sms, twilio-python

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can pass a newline character to the Twilio library via my python script which sends SMS messages.

I need to do this because I'm storing automated responses in a database which I'm querying based on end user input.

Right now, I have the response stored as a variable, which contains "\n" in an attempt to insert a line break. The code is as follows:

```
    client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    body = responses.message_body # 'Welcome! \n Thanks for signing up!'
    # SEND THE MESSAGE
    m = client.messages.create(
        to=to_number, from_=from_number, body=body))
```

Unfortunately, when I send the message, '\n' is rendered as a string instead of a line break.

I know the syntax is correct because when I test with this, the new line appears.

```
    client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    body = "Welcome! \n Thanks for signing up!"
    # SEND THE MESSAGE
    m = client.messages.create(
        to=to_number, from_=from_number, body=body))
```

Any help is appreciated. Please also let me know if there is more anyone needs for clarity.

Thanks!

Comment: The value of `responses.message_body` in the first bit of code is clearly not the same as `"Welcome! \n Thanks for signing up!"`. If you do `print(repr(responses.message_body))`, from your description, I suspect you will see `'Welcome! \\n Thanks for signing up!'`. If that is the case then do `body = responses.message_body.replace(r"\n", "\n")`

Comment: @BoarGules This solves my issue, thank you!